# Refreshing Eclipse with script using ant, cannot find project

Tags: ant, eclipse-plugin

I try to refresh eclipse as a last step of `Powershell-script`. I am located at ".../My_Project" and the .xml-file is in "`.../My_Project/base/cmd`". Therefore the last line is

```
C:\app\eclipse_juno_SR2\eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -f .\base\cmd\refresh.xml -consolelog
```

And script i use is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="refresh_project" default="refresh" basedir="./../..">
<target name="refresh">
    <eclipse.refreshLocal resource="/My_Project" depth="infinite"/>
</target>
</project>
```

When i'm using it inside eclipse, the build works but when using the script it just shows this message:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration
 bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry aft
er the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: C:\Users\Dennis.Hert
el\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration\logback.1.
3.0.20130129-0926.xml
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: eclipse.consoleLog=true
Buildfile: .\base\cmd\refresh.xml

refresh:
[eclipse.refreshLocal] Warning: project /My_Project does not exist and cannot be
refreshed.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I tried

1. Several Projects
2. `eclipse.convertPath fileSystemPath="/My_Project"`
3. `property="Test" fileSystemPath="/${workspace_loc}/My_Project"`
4. `fileSystemPath="/${workspace_loc:My_Project}"`
5. `fileSystemPath="/path/to/my/project/My_Project"`
6. Using other environment-variables and use `${Test}` as resource

But it either do not expand the variable (workspace) or throws an error because the path is invalid (which it isn't) or nothing changes

Please excuse me if this is a stupid question, I'm working on it for hours, i have never used ant before and hope I'm not as stupid as i think

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the workspace that the Eclipse instance that you are running your ant script in is not the same workspace where the project is located.  To get around this, make sure you specify the Eclipse workspace location at the startup of the ant script.  You can use the `osgi.instance.area` system property to set the workspace location from the command that starts the script

```
-Dosgi.instance.area=/path/to/my/workspace
```

[Here is a complete description of the command line option.](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)